# Who are these characters on Earth 2?

Tags: character, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In ***Crisis on Infinite Earths*** part 5 of ***Arrowverse*** they

> reboot the whole universe and a new universe is formed.

It is shown that on Earth 2 there reside **Stargirl** and some other heroes. Who are these other heroes shown along with Stargirl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Unconfirmed but I believe that these are (via [**Den of Geek**](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/stargirl/275021/stargirl-tv-series-dc-universe)):

### Stripe Robot (rear)

> Luke Wilson will play Courtney's stepfather, crimefighting partner, and former superhero sidekick Pat Dugan, the pilot of the STRIPE robot. Here's the official character description...
>
> > “Pat Dugan once went by the less-than-inspired superhero name of Stripesy, sidekick to a young hero known as the Star-Spangled-Kid and later Starman of the legendary Justice Society of America. Today, Pat has left his sidekick life behind him. But when his new step-daughter, Courtney Whitmore, discovers Pat’s secret past and takes on Starman’s legacy to become Stargirl, Pat is forced to come out of retirement and once again become a sidekick — to his step-daughter — this time piloting a 15-foot robot called Stripe.”

### Dr Mid-Nite (front row - far left)

> "Also known as the introspective surgeon Dr. Charles McNider, Dr. Mid-Nite is a brilliant and forward-thinking medical pioneer, and a founding member of the JSA. With his trusty owl, he acts as the team’s resident doctor and detective."

[image]

### Hourman (front - middle)

> Rex Tyler, the Golden Age Hourman, described by TV Line as "a master chemist and adrenaline junkie who as Hourman is a thrill-seeking superhero with the ability to manifest super-strength… for one hour a day. A founding member of the Justice Society of America, Rex/Hourman struggles with balancing his life as a hero and father."

[image]

### Wildcat (front - right)

Based on [this article](https://fullcirclecinema.com/2019/08/22/stargirl-yvette-monreal-wildcat-costume/) and image this seem to be Wildcat

> Earlier this year, it was revealed that The Fosters actress Yvette Monreal would be playing on Yolonda Montez, aka Wildcat on DC Universe’s Stargirl. Now, thanks to Thomas Polito of GWW, we have our first look at Monreal’s costume on the set of the series.

[image]

Comment: The front right, although not 100% confirmed, is dressed in the Wildcat costume, which was absolutely a character from the JSA era.

Comment: Hmmm...possible but the article linked seems to indicate that their is a *male* Wildcat character but it's possible the name will be passed to another person.

Comment: Wait..found confirmation this is Wildcat - editing.